# How to use multiple credentials in withCredentials in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I have the following step in my declarative jenkins pipeline:
I create script which comes from my `resources/` folder using libraryResource. This script contains credentials for my `autobuild` user and for some `admintest` user.

```
stage('Build1') {
                steps {
                    node{
                        def script = libraryResource 'tests/test.sh'
                        writeFile file: 'script.sh', text: script
                        sh 'chmod +x script.sh'
                        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: xxx, usernameVariable: 'AUTOBUILD_USER', passwordVariable: 'AUTOBUILD_PASSWD')]){
                            sh './script.sh "
                        }

                    }

                }
```

This works fine. I can use my `autobuild` user. Now I'm searching for the best way how I can include also the crendentials of my `admintest` user.
Do I have to 'nest' it with a second `withCredentials` part or can I add again a `usernamePassword` 'array'?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Sure, you can use one `withCredentials` block to assign multiple credentials to different variables.

```
withCredentials([
    usernamePassword(credentialsId: credsId1, usernameVariable: 'USER1', passwordVariable: 'PASS1'),
    usernamePassword(credentialsId: credsId2, usernameVariable: 'USER2', passwordVariable: 'PASS2')
]){
    //...
}
```

Comment: How to do this with Groovy?

Comment: @meshfields this is Groovy

Comment: @SteveK stage('stage 2') {
            steps{
                  withCredentials([usernamePassword(usernameVariable: 'user_1', passwordVariable: 'password_1', credentialsId: 'id_1'),
                                   usernamePassword(usernameVariable: 'username_2', passwordVariable: 'password_2', credentialsId: 'id_2')]){
                    sshagent(credentials : ['jenkins_ssh_user_key']) {
                   sh """
                   """
                }
              }
            }
        }

Answer (score 11):

Also, you can use this with $class

```
                    withCredentials([[
                      $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                      credentialsId: 'awsID',
                      accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                      secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],

                    [$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
                      credentialsId: 'myID',
                      usernameVariable: 'USR',
                      passwordVariable: 'PWD']])
```

Comment: Any class for string text