# How to pass jenkins passwords into ansible playbook via pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

How to inject passwords to the build as environment variables(these are job passwords)  for deployment through ansible via pipeline or dsl script

Answer (score 1):

First, those job passwords should be [registered as credentials](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-secure-guide/injecting-secrets#_defining_credentials_and_secrets) inside Jenkins.

Second, you can use said file when calling your [`ansible-playbook` command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html), through the [Credentials Binding plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#credentials-binding-plugin).
See "[How to use multiple credentials in withCredentials in Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47475160/6309)"

```yaml
node {
  withCredentials([
    usernamePassword(credentialsId: credsId1, usernameVariable: 'USER1', passwordVariable: 'PASS1'),
    usernamePassword(credentialsId: credsId2, usernameVariable: 'USER2', passwordVariable: 'PASS2')
    ...
  ]) {
    sh '''
      set +x
      ansible-playbook /path/to/ansible-playbook.yml -i /path/to/hosts_list -u AUTO_USER --private-key=/path/to/private-key \
      -e $USER1=$PASS1 -e $USER2=$PASS2
    '''
  }
}
```

Note: the file should have a JSON content, with your